# Boost Spirit rule with custom attribute parsing

Tags: boost, attributes, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix

I am writing a Boost Spirit grammar to parse text into a vector of these structs:

```
struct Pair
{
    double a;
    double b;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Pair,
    (double, a)
    (double, a)
)
```

This grammar has a rule like this:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, Pair()> pairSequence;
```

However, the actual grammar of `pairSequence` is this:

```
double_ % separator
```

I want this grammar to produce a `Pair` with `a` equal to the double and `b` equal to some constant.  I want to do something like this:

```
pairSequence = double_[_val = Pair(_1, DEFAULT_B)] % separator;
```

The above does not compile, of course.  I tried adding a constructor to `Pair`, but I still get compile errors (*no matching function for call to 'Pair::Pair(const boost::phoenix::actor >&, double)'*).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the signature of `pairSequence` needs to be:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<Pair>()> pairSequence;
```

as the list operator exposes a `std::vector<Pair>` as its attribute.

All functions called from inside a semantic action have to be 'lazy', so you need to utilize phoenix:

```
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

pairSequence = 
    double_[
        phx::push_back(_val, 
            phx::construct<Pair>(_1, phx::val(DEFAULT_B))
        )
    ] % separator
;
```

Another possibility would be to add a (non-explicit) constructor to `Pair`:

```
struct Pair         
{         
    Pair(double a) : a(a), b(DEFAULT_B) {}

    double a;         
    double b;         
};
```

which allows to simplify the grammar:

```
pairSequence = double_ % separator;
```

and completely relies on Spirit's built-in attribute propagation rules.

BTW, for any of this to work, you don't need to adapt `Pair` as a Fusion sequence.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the vector<Pair> construct.